# Invert Background and Text Colours across Whole Document with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, color

When using pdflatex is there a simple way to invert the colors to give white text on a black background across the whole document? I'd like the colours to be inverted whilst I write and edit the document, and then to be able to switch back to black text on a white background for the final version

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with the `xcolor` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}
\begin{document}

Hello \clearpage World

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problems if you have some red, blue, ... text, figures, ... and what you want is to invert everything. :(

Comment: This will not work on the color of Enumerate section

Answer (score 8):

As no LaTeX solution:

- If you use evince as pdf viewer you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert *any* document. It will keep that setting for just that document even if you change and reload the document.
- Yo can use `xcalib -i -a` to invert a whole screen.

Comment: For which OS does this work?

Comment: @doncherry certainly for xubuntu 16.04. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend a more understandable way to write it using *commands*, based in the words of Lamport, "The LaTeX commands describe the *logical structure* of a Document' (See [LaTeX - User's Guide and Reference Manual](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~sivann/books/LaTeX%20-%20User's%20Guide%20and%20Reference%20Manual-lamport94.pdf), Sect 2.2).

```
%Commands definitions
\newcommand{\setbackgroundcolour}{\pagecolor[rgb]{0.19,0.19,0.19}}  
\newcommand{\settextcolour}{\color[rgb]{0.77,0.77,0.77}}    
\newcommand{\invertbackgroundtext}{\setbackgroundcolour\settextcolour}

%Command execution. 
%If this line is commented, then the appearance remains as usual.
\invertbackgroundtext
```

A bit more work, but a more readable document. Moreover, when you do not want to change the colours, you have only to comment out the command `\invertbackgroundtext`

Note: instead of `0.5` and `1`, I used `0.19` for background and `0.77` for text—I think these colours give a lesser *eye strain*.