# Creating pdf with inverted colors using pdflatex (like white on black etc)

Tags: pdf, color

Is there a simple way of a creating PDF with inverted colours?

A partial solution would be just changing font to white and making the background black.

Is there simple "full" solution of inverting whole PDF pages? (including colors in `lstlistings`, images, etc)

Comment: It will likely be most efficient to do this with ghostscript.

Comment: For local viewing I use `xpdf -rv` or [invert entire screen with `xcalib -i -a`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/invert-colors-of-the-active-window).

Comment: I'd like to invert whole pdf-s. Ghostscript sounds interesting, but I'm afraid of loosing hyperref links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40495/invert-background-and-text-colours-across-whole-document-with-pdflatex

Answer (score 3):

You can set a `pagecolor` with the background package and the page color using the `color` command. You will need to pass the values onto `setlistings` as well. Color inversion of images is perhaps not possible although you can manipulate them as well. What do you exactly want the images to look like?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{teX}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
   numbers=left,numberstyle=\normalsize,stepnumber=1,numbersep=5pt,
   breaklines=true,
   %firstnumber=last,
       %frame=tblr,
       framesep=5pt,
       basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
       showstringspaces=false,
       keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{orange},
      %identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
       stringstyle=\color{maroon},
    commentstyle=\color{black},
    rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    xrightmargin=0pt,
    aboveskip=\medskipamount,
    belowskip=\medskipamount,
       backgroundcolor=\color{black}, #1
}}
{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{background}
\SetBgContents{}
\begin{document}
 \pagecolor{black}
 \color{green}
\begin{teX}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{teX}[1][]
\end{teX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just would like to invert colors of whole pages. This can be done by generating pdf first and than including it and reverting colors. I mentioned about images, just because I don't want to change settings of each used object, but to have a kind of global switch.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki You will then have to look at external tools, or add a switch as an option when you generate the pdf i.e., the `pagecolor` and `color` can be set to be activated via an if statement. Best tool externally is Acrobat Professional.

Comment: It's not available for Linux and it's 270$ for commercial use, for Teachers is 120$. I will not pay 120$, just for inverting colors in my pdf ;).

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I would invest 2 minutes and get a trial version ; besides in Poland anything is possible;)

Answer (score 1):

A better solution (perhaps the best solution) is to use [`crop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/crop) package with `invert` option.

Comment: Not really: "This option doesn’t invert pictures, nor does it really swap text and paper color."